# How to debug bundled TypeScript files in .NET Core project?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, asp.net-core

I use JavaScript bundler to bundle my all compiled TypeScript files into one file.

Works as charm except one thing: debugging of TypeScript doesn't work (breakpoints in TypeScript are not triggered). If the files are included independently, no problem.

However it IS a problem for me. I have many TypeScript files (modules) in my project and I want to include them in some views, and in some I don't. I surely don't want to keep my full list of modules copied in multiple cshtml files. It would make adding a new file or refactoring one a nightmare.

So now my bundler is configured like this (in bundlerconfig.json):

```
[
    {
        "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
        "inputFiles": [
            "wwwroot/css/site.css"
        ]
    }
    ,
    {
        "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/modules.min.js",
        "includeInProject": false,
        "inputFiles": [
            "wwwroot/modules/**/*.js"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "minify": {
            "enabled": true,
            "renameLocals": true
        }
    }
]
```

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

Here's a view header that uses it (Logon.cshtml):

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/js/modules.min.js"></script>
}
<!-- view definition ... -->
```

So, I add a new TypeScript class, it's auto-magically compiled and bundled. But I cannot debug it in Visual Studio. If I add the individual file, I can.

I need debugging, but I also need my modules list in one place. Adding dozens of `script` tags into multiple cshtml files is crazy.

Is there a smart solution to this? Could I somehow generate source maps mapping TypeScript files to bundled and minified common file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my partial solution to this problem:

```
@section scripts {
#if DEBUG
Html.RenderPartial("Modules.cshtml");
#else
<script src="~/js/modules.min.js"></script>
#endif
}
```

File `Modules.cshtml` contains all script tags for each generated JS used in project. It's used only in debug configuration (so separate files are loaded), in release configuration bundled and minified version is used instead.

It requires to manually update the `Modules.cshtml` file, so it's sub-optimal.

Still, I'd prefer to map multiple TypeScript files to one JavaScript bundle.